# Creating a chess board with system.out.println() in java

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to create a chessboard that looks like this:

```
---------------------------------
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
---------------------------------
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
---------------------------------
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
---------------------------------
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
---------------------------------
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
---------------------------------
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
---------------------------------
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
---------------------------------
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
---------------------------------
```

For some reason I cant get the last line on each row to appear where it suppose to.

Here is my code

```
   public static final int BOARD_SIZE = 8;

   public void displayChessBoard(){
      for (int row = 0; row < BOARD_SIZE; row++)
      {
          System.out.println("");
          System.out.println("---------------------------------");

          for (int column = 0; column < BOARD_SIZE; column++)
          {
              System.out.print("| " + " " + " ");
          }           
    }
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("---------------------------------");
  }
```

`main` just calls the method `displayChessBoard()`.

Here is my output

```
---------------------------------
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   
---------------------------------
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   
---------------------------------
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   
---------------------------------
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   
---------------------------------
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   
---------------------------------
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   
---------------------------------
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   
---------------------------------
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   
---------------------------------
```

Comment: where does the row end up?

Comment: show your current output??

Comment: i updated the question showing the output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add another print after the inner `for`. Like this:

```
for (int row = 0; row < BOARD_SIZE; row++)
  {
      System.out.println("");
      System.out.println("---------------------------------");

      for (int column = 0; column < BOARD_SIZE; column++)
      {
          System.out.print("| " + " " + " ");
      }       
      System.out.print("|");
    }
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("---------------------------------");
```

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 1):

You are printing 7 pipes, inner `for` cycle is going from 0 to 7 (`column < BOARD_SIZE`), just add a pipe print after inner cycle's end.

If you don't mind extra spaces at the end of each line just change `for` condition to `column <= BOARD_SIZE`.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the BOARD_SIZE in second for-statement to 9:

This code generates the chess board just like you want:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    for (int row = 0; row < 8; row++)
    {
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("---------------------------------");

        for (int column = 0; column < 9; column++)
        {
            System.out.print("| " + " " + " ");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("---------------------------------");
}
```

Comment: this creates some empty spaces "outside" of the chessboard, nvm if it doesnt matter